# How to get images from the .tex folder (relative path) in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to get a watermark image like here:

[How to add a watermark image on rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746947/how-to-add-a-watermark-image-on-rmarkdown)

I almost did it, but as I wrote on my original question the `background.png` image that the `\includegraphics` get comes from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\plain\present`

I'm currently using my Latex code from an external file using the follwing at beginning of my .Rmd:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
```

And in `header.tex` I'm using the following code:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\centering
  {\transparent{0.3} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}}%
    }
  }
}
```

But I just can't get the `background.png` from where my `.tex` file is (that is the same that my `.Rmd` file is).

How I tell to my `.tex` file get this image from the relative path to my `.tex`?

--EDIT-- 
I'm using the `render` function from `rmarkdown` to make the report, follow is a screenshot from the insides of my folder with .Rmd, the .tex file and the error when I try to insert a `test.png`:

[image: rstudio screenshot]

Comment: What is the actual error?  I have used `\includegraphics{...}` lots of times via `rmarkdown`, mostly with a simple subdirectory as in, say, `\includegraphics{figures/someChart.pdf}`.  Pandoc just passes that through unchanged and (la)tex processes as usual.

Comment: If I change the background.png to test.png, for instance, it gives me the error: `! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'test.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it.

The problem were on MiKTeX for Windows.

I just followed the steps on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136307), remembering to assure that the folder is TDS-compliant (with a `tex` folder in it), and after I just put the image on the `tex` folder.

Answer (score 1):

"It works for me."  Here is a minimal Rmarkdown file, trimmed down from one of the templates offered by RStudio:

````
---
title: "Demo"
author: "Dirk"
date: "October 3, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. We include one figure

\includegraphics{Rlogo.png}

La fin.
````

I can hit the `knit` button just fine, or run this by hand:

````
/tmp$ cat includeDemo.Rmd
---
title: "Demo"
author: "Dirk"
date: "October 3, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. We include one figure

\includegraphics{Rlogo.png}

La fin.

/tmp$ Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("includeDemo.Rmd")'


processing file: includeDemo.Rmd
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: includeDemo.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS includeDemo.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output includeDemo.pdf --template /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.15.2.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 

Output created: includeDemo.pdf
/tmp$
````

Maybe *something* is playing tricks with you by switching from the current directory to a temporary processing directory.  In which an (icky!!) absolute path may help...

[image]