# Add watermark image in TOC of RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to add a watermark image to the background of my Table of Contents page only. I have tried a combination of the following questions:

[How to Obtain A Watermark Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833768/how-to-get-images-from-the-tex-folder-relative-path-in-rmarkdown/39835946#39835946)

[Add an Image In The Title Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389149/add-image-in-title-page-of-rmarkdown-pdf)

Below is the contents of my example.Rmd file. I use the Knit button in RStudio to turn it into a .pdf.

```
---
title: <center> <h1>Example Report</h1> </center>
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs} 
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
- \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}\vspace{-2cm} 
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: {10}
geometry: margin=0.20in

---
```

I have tried, using the code below, adding the image as a post title but there is a big space left after the title and before the TOC:

```
    ---
    title: <center> <h1>Example Report</h1> </center>
    header-includes:
    - \usepackage{titling}
    - \pretitle{\begin{center}}
    - \posttitle{\end{center}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=12cm]{my_graphic.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
    - \usepackage{booktabs} 
    - \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering}
    - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}\vspace{-2cm} 
    mainfont: Arial
    output:
      pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
    sansfont: Arial
    fig_crop: false
    toc: true
    classoption: landscape
    fontsize: {10}
    geometry: margin=0.20in

    ---
```

How do I please center, create a watermark and place the image behind the TOC rather than in-front?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why using `HTML` and `CSS` when outputting a pdf?

Comment: The CSS is redundant and a straight copy/ paste from this example. I have removed for this purpose.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63379/92139 ?