# how to use rmarkdown to generate reports with watermarks text logos

Tags: r

Could you please help me to understand how to generate reports with watermarks text logos. could you please provide the steps to achieve the same.

I want to generate the word document with the watermark text logos.

I have no idea how to proceed with it. but i tried something below with the yaml

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748248/watermark-in-rmarkdown

Comment: I tried something with the YAML but does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You can watermark a Word document by using a template file via the `reference_docx` option that includes a watermark. You need to make sure that the template includes the style elements like title, heading 1, heading 2, etc., that you want to make use of; otherwise the resulting document will not make use of these styles.

Follow this workflow to achieve this:

1. Create an Rmd with all the style elements you will use.
2. Render it as a word document and open it.
3. [Insert a watermark](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-watermark-f90f26a5-2101-4a75-bbfe-f27ef05002de) and save as a new file.
4. Render your Rmd with the `reference_docx` option pointing to the watermarked docx.

Include the `reference_docx` option like so:

```
---
title: "Watermark Test"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: watermark.docx
---
```